# Wondering if PHP has a function like Android ListView

Tags: php, listview

I have been trying to find out if there is a function in PHP that is similar to Android's [`ListView`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)?

I have some data in my database that I want to load into a list. Any help is appreciated; I'm very new to this, thanks!

Comment: You should post some example code ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  Include what you've already tried and where exactly you're stuck. See more info at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thanks!

Comment: Do you need help loading data from your database in a list using PHP, or do you need help to code the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry, it doesn't. The "User Interface" is provided by HTML, not PHP.

You didn't post your code, but, if you do, I can give you a more specific answer. You can use PHP code to generate HTML, though.